# QuickBlox : Error while trying to login into QBChat in iOS 9

Tags: ios, quickblox, xmppframework

I'm trying to login into QuickBlox Chat (`QBChat`) but couldn't login into iOS9 (running via XCode7 beta). It was working great in iOS 7 and 8. An error logs the following in debug console:

```
2015-07-06 17:56:47.464 MyApp[25156:251907] xmppStreamDidConnect
2015-07-06 17:56:47.464 MyApp[25156:251907] -[QBChat xmppStreamDidConnect:] -> Trying TLS...
2015-07-06 17:56:47.910 MyApp[25156:251916] -[QBChat xmppStreamDidDisconnect:withError:] -> error: 
Error Domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL Code=-9850 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error -9850.)" UserInfo=0x7f9dd962e430 
{NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Error code definition can be found in Apple's 
SecureTransport.h}
```

Today, I've updated my QuickBlox iOS SDK from 2.2 to 2.3. So I've setup everything as per they want.

Note, I'm able to create session but couldn't able to login into `QBChat`.

Here's my sample code:

```
QBSessionParameters *parameters = [QBSessionParameters new];
parameters.userLogin = ...;
parameters.userPassword = ...;

[QBRequest createSessionWithExtendedParameters:parameters successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {
    DLog(@"Success");

    QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];        
    user.ID = ...;
    user.password = ...;

    [[QBChat instance] addDelegate:self];

    [[QBChat instance] setAutoReconnectEnabled:YES];

    BOOL requestQBChatLogin = [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:user];
    if(!requestQBChatLogin) {
        //This will never prints in logs
        DLog(@"Something went wrong while sending request for QBChatLogin.");
    }

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    DLog(@"Error: %@", response.error);
}];

-(void) chatDidLogin{
    //This will never call
    DLog(@"You have successfully signed in to QuickBlox Chat!");
}

- (void) chatDidNotLogin {
    //This will never call
    DLog(@"You have not signed in to QuickBlox Chat!");
}
```

<sub>Please make sure that – I've added proper values for userName or ID or password as and when require.</sub>

Comment: I'm having same problem and I have checked the username, id and password, all correct. If someone could help would be great! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try again, this problem has been fixed. It works on iOS 9 beta 4+